# (R) Finding list elements by name and combine list elements into c()

Tags: r, list, r-s4

I have an S4 object named "S4" that contains the id and a list (or it can be changed into a data frame) named "color" that has the color information annotated to each id in R.

```
# S4 information - id: This is a printed example on my console
# S4@name$id 
# [1] "A" "B/b" "B/b" "C"

# Color list
color = list(
"A" = "red", 
"B/b" = "yellow", 
"C" = "blue")
```

I want to put all of the color names matched to the id to call the list elements of all the matched colors (ex. c("red", "yellow", "yellow")).

For formatting ids into a combined id names (ex. c("A", "B/b", "B/b", "C")), I tried the code below:

```
color = list(
"A" = "red", 
"B/b" = "yellow", 
"C" = "blue")

id <- c("A", "B/b", "B/b", "C") # this is a example to make id characters.

# cat(paste0('"', paste(id, collapse="\", \""), '"')) is to print all the ids with comma, but it is actually containing "\".
color[c(cat(paste0('"', paste(id, collapse="\", \""), '"')))]
```

This code is not working, and I wonder how I can revise the code to get all the ids into a combined characters to call the matched list elements of color names into a combined characters as same as id.

So final results would be:

```
# id information: c("A", "B/b", "B/b", "C") in the "color" list 
# Color list elements: c("red", "yellow", "yellow", "blue") to put all color names into another function
```

Any better approach would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `unlist(color[id])` or even `unlist(color)[id]`  should give you what you want. Maybe just `color[id]` if you need a list back

Comment: Don't use a `list` unless you need one - combining data types, nesting, ragged values, etc.  For associating 2 string values, use a data frame or even a named vector. `color = c(
"A" = "red", 
"B/b" = "yellow", 
"C" = "blue")` will let you do `color[id]` directly.

Comment: Maybe: `sapply(id, function(i) {color[[i]]})` will return a vector of the colors.

Comment: Thank you all! Both of ways all working great! 
Just trying to add some notes, this was for a function that requires color information only into a vector (ex. In S4@info, fill = red yellow yellow). For this type of function, it seems it is better to use a named vector to call their elements not the list.